# The use of "write" or "write down" in context

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Let's say a teacher is going to have their student to write a few example sentences with a certain word in their notebook. Would they say *write* or *write down* to tell the students to do that. For example:

> Now I want you to **write** a few example sentences in the present continuous.
>
> Now I want you to **write down** a few example sentences in the present continuous.

Can both be used in the context? If so, is there any difference in meaning between them?

Comment: Same thing but down is more emphatic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between **write** and **write down**.

- **Write** speaks about composing something: a sentence, a book, a phrase, a poem.
- **Write down** means *to put something into writing*, *to apply writing onto a piece of paper or some other material*.

If the students are asked to "**write**" a few sentences this may either may to compose them and then write them down or to just write down what the teacher will be telling them. However, if they are asked to "**write down**" a few sentences then the sentence already exist and should simply be placed into writing.

Comment: But what if I said "write down a few English verbs and make a few sentences with them". It is obvious that you cannot compose English verbs. Can I use "write" in the sentence with the same meaning there?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope You can compose them in your head (bring them up in your memory) and then write them down.

Comment: So they are interchangable in my sentence in the comment, right?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope No, they have a different meaning. Reread the answer.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope as this answer makes clear, "write down" means putting down on paper something that already exists. For example, a teacher might tell their students to "write down" a sentence that is already on the blackboard. To use "write down" correctly in the situation you describe, the teacher would say "Now, I want you to [find/make up/think of] some sentences in present continuous and write them down".